# Why was the C-pennant chosen as the flag of ships from Allied-occupied Germany?

Tags: germany, ships, flags

Is there any evidence explaining why the Allies chose the [C-pennant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Germany#After_World_War_II_(1945%E2%80%9349)), instead of [a more intuitive letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags)? Why not G (for Germany) or D (for Deutschland)?

[image]

[Or A for Allemagne, or S for Sachsa, or N for Německo, P for Purutia, or U for Ubudage, or T for Teutschland, or V for Vācija or F for Frángoi...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Germany#List_of_area_names). I had a look at the article Names of Germany, and 15 out of 26 letters have been the first letter of Germany's name, in some language at some point in time. That's not counting words for a German person, only the country Germany. So, it seems that it wasn't chosen for that reason... if they'd just picked a random letter there was a greater than 50% chance it would have matched up with one of those names!

Comment: Has it's own WP page here https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erkennungsflagge_f%C3%BCr_deutsche_Handelsschiffe where it's stated in 'discussions' that 'there are theories'. But no proof. Perhaps upgrade the question (to reduce a necessary frame-challenge over inaccuracies in this Q about form and scope of the actual flag) and to emphasise the 'why' and ask explicitly for 'evidence' as to how this flag came about?

Comment: Article 1 of Law 39 states: **wear the Allied Control Authority distinguishing flag** [Pdf page 166](https://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/Enactments/Volume-V.pdf). The Directives 1-14 (Establishment of the **Allied Control Authority**, August 1945) does not meantion any special flag to represent them. Assume a practical solution, with colors that represent the Allies and was readily available at the time. There were more important things to do than invent and produce a new flag.

Comment: *The flag state of a merchant vessel is **the jurisdiction** under whose laws the vessel is registered*. The jurisdiction in this case is the **Allied Control Authority**, not Germany.

Comment: There is probably some central registration of Mechant vessel agreements. Looking at their archives for 1946 would probably result in some notation about a Allied Control Authority distinguishing flag.

Comment: I've accepted answer that they probably just didn't want A or B and didn't think decision merited any more thought than picking 1st available letter. Disappointingly prosaic, but sometimes things are. If true it's basically unprovable - if there's more to it, happy to accept different answer.

Comment: Wrt other answer, we've seen many times questions relating to WW2 often attract plain bad answers or outright Nazi propaganda. I genuinely don't know which one this is. Tho strictly irrelevant, I'd like to point out that an inhabitant of a 'defeated enemy country' controlled by the Allies was much, much more fortunate that a citizen of a country 'liberated' by the Nazis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because [those other pennants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags) already had internationally recognized meanings, that would have resulted in dangerous ambiguities:

[image]

Note also the very specific instruction:

> The Council ruled that "no ceremony shall be accorded this flag which shall not be dipped in salute to warships or merchant ships of any nationality".

There was ***very intentionally*** no national character to be associated with the ensign.

**Update**

In particular, the **A** pennant already had the meaning:

> I have a diver down; keep well clear at slow speed."

and the "B" pennant the meaning:

> I am taking in or discharging or carrying dangerous goods.

Selecting either of these two alphabetically preceding penants would have been an absurd, bordering on insane, choice endangering lives.

In contrast the "C" pennant had the benign and innocuous meaning:

> Affirmative

Remember Occam's Razor at all times: The most likely explanation is the simplest one consistent with all known facts.

Comment: I can believe 'there was very intentionally no national character to be associated with the ensign'. However, there was a specific meaning for this pennant (however, there's no specific meaning for the pennant 'R')

Comment: I usually peruse the alphabet from A towards Z. I believe that is the norm for most persons, and thus one would start at the beginning and locate the first pennant thought to be suitable. 'C' occurs a long ways ahead of 'R'.

Comment: Haha! Yes, it could be as simple as that. I'll let the question stand, though, as there may have been more to it.

Comment: @Nemo: Of course - never be in a rush to accept, as that act tends to discourage further research.

Comment: I wonder if it was C for the allies' Control Commission, which governed Germany from 1945-9. However, I'm starting to think you might be right!

Comment: according to Wikipedia, "Similarly, the Japanese civil ensign used immediately following World War II was the signal pennant for the letter E ending in a swallowtail, and the Ryūkyūan civil ensign was a swallowtailed letter D signal pennant." which seems inconsistent with the given reason for avoiding D.

Comment: @NeMo - re "However, there was a specific meaning for this pennant": note that its meaning is a confirmation to a previous message, so having it raised before any previous communication cannot be misinterpreted.

Comment: According to the [German Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flagge_Deutschlands#1945_bis_1949), "Die Farben blau, weiß und rot repräsentieren dabei die Nationalfarben der vier Alliierten." (*"The colors blue, white and red in this represented the national colors of the four Allied powers."*) The statement is, however, not sourced individually.

Comment: @DevSolar; Since 1789 the colours blue, white, and red together in a flag have represented only liberty, equality and fraternity. Stop such nonsense.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I am citing additional information from DE:WP. Stop such hostility.

Comment: @DevSolar: Grow a sense of humour why not. I am pointing out how easy it is to make things up after the fact. The sentence "*Stop such nonsense.*" has been a universal tell for a joke for decades. I thought that was recognizable to all native English speakers. If not, my apologies.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: You ever heard about [Poe's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe's_law), or [smileys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley)? ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar: I thought that particular expression was well enough known and recognizable to not need it. I was incorrect.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I take it as a compliment that you consider me a native speaker (since I am not). ;-) No offense taken, sorry for getting my hackles up like that.

Comment: @DevSolar: No harm, no foul. Enjoy this fine (Canadian) Thanksgiving Holiday.

Comment: Hmm - i'm not sure about this answer. D, E and O were used for Japan / Ryukyu islands / US ships operating in japanese waters. I assume that "C" was derived from "Control Council", D and E just continuing that line.

Comment: @tohuwawohu: Identification of origin is still necessary. Your point would seem more applicable as a refutation of the proposed answer following.

Comment: http://www.vexillum.com/fotw/flags/de1945.html The "Because"-part seems incorrect to me. With the razor method that also looks at Japan, and the other A on this page, I conclude that we do not know any answer to the 'why' part of this question? (In particular curiosity, I also don't see any connection to "*the* colours" of "3" or sometimes "4" allies' forces represented? Another retrofit explanation?)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: i agree completely

Comment: I ultimately accepted this answer - short version, *because they didn't like A or B* - however the fact that D and E were used for Japan casts some doubt on your explanation of why they didn't choose A or B. D and E also have highly specific meanings which it would be dangerous to misconstrue.

Answer (score 2):

Historical vexillologists do *not* know a definitive answer.

What is known is that the Allied Control Council Law No 39 from November 1946 made it mandatory to display such a c-pennant-like flag instead  of a 'national flag', but *not as* a national flag (meaning also not at the usual position on masts etc). ([Law 39](https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/de1945.html) on page 166 [PDF](https://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/Enactments/Volume-V.pdf), German translation on [WP: Erkennungsflagge für deutsche Handelsschiffe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erkennungsflagge_f%C3%BCr_deutsche_Handelsschiffe)).

This was done as *all* German flags were ordered illegal as of May 1945, but in international waters a ship would still need this kind of identification. Absolutely no flags would mean in international law that a ship was stateless or engaged in piracy… From May 1945 onwards there were absolutely *no German flags* allowed.

> (g) Administrative Affairs. Other measures refer to administrative matters requiring uniform regulation by a central agency, such as adopting standard time throughout Germany; arranging for a population census; and certain arrangements *incidental on the occupation and its technical requirements.<sup>120</sup>*
>
> <sup>120:</sup> Law No. 39 of Nov. 12, 1946 on "Distinguishing Flag to be Worn by German
> and Ex-German Ships Operating Under Allied Control Authority," OG/CC, No. 12 at 226 (Nov. 30, 1946);
> <sub>— Karl Loewenstein: "Law and The Legislative Process in Occupied Germany: I", The Yale Law Journal, Vol. 57, 724, 1948. (PDF)</sub>

As the text of this law from 1946 makes explicit (in excerpt):

> Article 1
>
> 1. In all cases, except as provided in Article III, **every German or ex-German vessel operating under the allied Control Authority** shall at all times wear **the Allied Control Authority distinguishing flag** which shall consist of Inter­national Flag "C" with a triangle cut from the fly, as shown in the Schedule hereto,
> 2. This flag […] and shall be treated as a distinguishing flag.

There is rife speculation as to whether the meaning of "C" was meant as a constant reminder of defeat as it would stand as an abbreviation for 'C'apitulation. Certainly, this was a 'popular' *German* interpretation for this derogatorily called "bathing pants flag", as even the German minister for transport [Seebohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans-Christoph_Seebohm) (Hans-Christoph, not the Nazi-admiral Hans!) alluded to this reading in 1951 when the first black-red-gold German national flag on ships was again allowed to be flown on ships:

> Everyone knows the symbolic meaning associated with this flag.
> <sub>— [Seebohm when on board the first ship with the new flag, MS Messina, 23 February 1951](https://www.abendblatt.de/70jahre/chronik/chronik-1951/). (quoted from Biegler)</sub>

Other speculations are for example from Stödter who maintains that the letter C would also allude to [prizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prize_(law)) (meaning that it would be effective even long *before* the official capitulaion/surrender), as such would be the quasi-official collective status for German ships after 1945.

Biegler himself prefers – *without* better evidence – that it would be short for "Control", as in 'Control Council'. And that the colours present in that pennant would indeed match all 4 allies' national flags.

— Thilo Biegler: "Flaggenführung der Schiffe und Boote der Deutschen Kriegsmarine nach der Kapitulation 1945", Fahnen Flags Drapeaux (Proceedings of the 15<sup>th</sup> ICV, Zurich, 1993. [PDF](http://internationalcongressesofvexillology-proceedingsandreports.yolasite.com/resources/15th_Zurich/Biegler-DeutschenKriegsmarine.pdf))

At least the name of the flag is also mentioned prior to Law No 39 in Directive 33 (5), August 16th, 1946 "Limitations of the Characteristics of Ships Left at the Disposal of Germany", ([PDF](https://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/Enactments/Volume-IV.pdf), PDF-p72/p60)) as the 'Allied Authority Control flag'.

However, these speculations do not have any direct evidence to support them, but also a few circumstantial data points that make them less plausible.

The first would be that for Japan, three different flags were ordered in much the same manner, but obviously different from the 'German' identification flag — and without any such readily interpretable letter meaning:

Two 'Japanese' flags meaning

> - "E"/"I am altering my course to starboard."?
> - "D"/"Keep clear of me; I am maneuvering with difficulty."?

The third then a  modified "O" carrying "man overboard meaning" as a flag?

Why would the German version get such a 'special meaning' by intention but not the Japanese versions?

The next objection would be found in the timing. Already on May 7th 1945 German ships were ordered to display a black flag or a blue flag as a sign of surrender. Additionally, allied ships were ordered to also accept a white flag for the same purpose.

Then already on May 9th 1945 a provisional order went out that proscribed for German or ex-German ships to have the C-pennant. That order and the British practice to talk about "under allied control" and this pennant as literally the "control flag" might mean indeed that 'C'ontrol was an early meaning that for very simple and practical reasons then was solidified into Law No 39?

It might be added that in German flag alphabets it is also listed as

> [C – Charlie – Yes](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaggenalphabet)

and in regatta sports as

> ["change of course in the next section"](http://www.segelclub-preetz.de/index.php/regatta/regelkunde/flaggenkunde)

The British War Diary Summaries record this:

> WDS, radio, 9.5 1945. .From ANCXF.
>
> To All Flag Officers in Charge and Naval Officers in Charge.
>
> (1) German war and merchant vessels required to operate in Allied interests with German crews are to fly at the peak International Code Flag C with a triangle cut from the fly thus transforming it into a burgee.
>
> (2) If Allied naval officers are onboard the appropriate Allied Ensign is also to be worn superior.
>
> (3) This arrangement is provisional.*
> <sub>— quoted from Biegel</sub>

> [A burgee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgee) is a distinguishing flag, regardless of its shape, of a recreational boating organization. In most cases, they have the shape of a pennant.

Notice that there are exceptions to 'all vessels': for the [German Mine Sweeping Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Mine_Sweeping_Administration) ships flew the signal*s* "eight" and "Nanni", ten in addition the c-pennant and after its dissolution the CCG-flag. The successor organisation ["Labor Unit B"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labor_Service_Unit_(B)) were all German manned but flew the Star & Stripes…  [Ships on Soviet controlled territory a simple red 'worker's' flag.](https://www.ddr-binnenschifffahrt.de/symbolefarben-001.htm) The order to hoist the "eight" signal-pennant was actually the last flag order of the Reishkriegsmarine issued by Dönitz on May 16 1945 (B.Nr .1.Skl. I i1212/45 [PDF](https://dr-herzfeld.de/flaggenkunde/flaggenverordnung.pdf)) (Incidentally, many captains also flew the signal "Q", without orders to do so. Which some say was a sign of protest over the 'no-flag' situation, as that should stand for *Quatsch* German für 'bullshit'. Nanni and Q were often confused.) It is remarkable that this last act of the Reichsregierung survived as a practical solution.

The German *national* version signal flag for "Nanny" or "Northpole" (and "8", "Q") looked like this:

[image] [image]

And a comparison of 'flags' from Biegler:

[image]

The most important thing to observe might be the simple fact that neither Germany nor Japan were allowed to display any form of true national flag in that period. So my own speculation here is that *any* non-national flag would have made sense and fulfilled the purpose. Unless a British Navy internal for this rationale is dug up: the actual choice made in Law No 39 looks much like mere contingency based on prior art.

Some further reading elucidating a few of the legal implications as written by a German official: – Ministerialrat Heinz Kallus: "Gesetzgeberische Arbeiten der Bundesregierung auf dem Gebiet des öffentlichen Seerechts", Schriften des deutschen Vereins für Internationales Seerecht Reihe A: Berichte und Vorträge, Heft 3, Schiffahrts-Verlag Hansa. C. Schroedter & Co.: Hamburg, 1954. ([PDF](https://www.seerecht.de/wp-content/uploads/dvis-schriftenreihe-a-heft-003.pdf)) And the [maritime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_flag) legal requirements and implications in [WP: Flag state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_state), as well as — John N. K. Mansell: "Flag State Responsibility: Historical Development and Contemporary Issues", Springer: Berlin Heidelberg, 2009.

Comment: Quoting Article 1 of Law 39 in full, where the words: **wear the Allied Control Authority distinguishing flag** are used would make this answer more useful. The purpose of a flag, for a merchant vessel, was to show under which **the jurisdiction** ([Flag state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_state#:~:text=The%20flag%20state%20of%20a,in%20which%20it%20is%20registered)) it is registered under. The text make it clear that this flag represents the **Allied Control Authority** and not Germany. The reason for the choice is not stated. Everything else is speculation.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Indeed, the main point of my A is that there is lots of speculation going around. Plus: 'the law' doesn't say anything about the reasons. But it is even more significant that they just extended the provisional practice from (pre-?)1945 into this later law in 1946. So, the Royal Navy's choice is where to look first for any rationale, should there be any…

Comment: Directive 33 (5) of the 16th of August 1946 [Pdf page 72](https://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/Enactments/Volume-IV.pdf) also mentions **the Allied Authority Control flag**.  So this was obviously defined somewhere at some point.

Answer (score -3):

> The by order of the allies since 1945 by german ships to use flag is corresponding to the flag C of the signal-flag-alphabet. Behind this conceals the humiliating intention to let ride german ships on the oceans only with the letter C, standing for Capitulation. Costa Rica made an appeal against this practice, because it is self using such a flag as national flag. In this way they have the c-flag rectangular carved on the flying end. With the founding of the FRG and the GDR, this practice was eliminated.
>
> > "Germany will not be occupied for the purpose of liberation but as a defeated enemy nation."
>
> US-american Directive of Occupation JCS 1067
>
> [image]

- [Ship flag: occupied Germany 1945–1949](https://www.flaggenlexikon.de/fdtlhiaf.htm)

Comment: What's the authoritative source for this claim?

Comment: The link is broken - can it be restored?

Comment: This is indeed repeated in several books on the subject, but not really related to JCS1067, but 'Control Council law No 39'. The actual *'why'* isn't answered there either, and hard evidence for this assertion ('c for capitulation') is lacking everywhere. It looks pretty much like a later retro-invention explanation (invented or interpreted as such by the Germans!), as it is not applicable to Japan, which also 'capitulated'/surrendered, but got other temp signal flags assigned.

Comment: JCS1067 didn't have much practical impact and was formally abrogated after two years (replaced by JCS 1779/1), so i doubt strongly that picking a single sentence from that document supports the view that "humiliation" was the primary aim of selecting the C pennant (and the reason to keep it up until 1949). Anyway, it's really worth reading that document completely: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/JCS_1067 - btw: since Nazi Germany did unconditionally surrender, wouldn't an "U" or an "S" (or both "U" + "S") be more appropriate if "humiliation" was intended?

Comment: @tohuwawohu Indeed, JCS is used quite circumstantial here, and already no longer relevant when the CC law proscribed *this* flag, for ships alone, but kept law until 1959! The Costa Rica angle is also dubious. But notice that quite some books now make this unsourced claim and Google presents this as the 'non-conspiratorial-approved' little top box on the results page when asking the question… What'd be nice if we here could be better than those copycat books, google or WP (abusing this maritime flag to stand for 'occupied Germany').

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect and purely speculative. Article 1 of Law 39 states *wear the **Allied Control Authority** distinguishing flag* to represent them as the registered authority ([Flag state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_state#:~:text=The%20flag%20state%20of%20a,in%20which%20it%20is%20registered)). Article 5 states that it comes into effect 2 months after publication that was done on the 17th of November 1946 (thus in **1947**).